# Pandas: Get percentile value by specific rows

Tags: python, pandas

i try to get the percentile of the value in column value, based on min and max column

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'value': [20, 10, -5, ],
     'min': [0, 10, -10,],
    'max': [40, 20, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I obtain a new column "percentile", which looks like this:

```
d = {'value': [20, 10, -5, ],
 'min': [0, 10, -10,],
'max': [40, 20, 0],
'percentile':[50, 0, 50]}
df_res = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_res
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to offset the min so that it becomes a ratio between value and max. You can do :

```py
df['percentile'] = (df['value'] - df['min']) / (df['max'] - df['min']) * 100
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept it as the answer so that is disappears from the unanswered question list :)